# How do I keep the screen on a console-only Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, console, power-management, monitors, buildroot

Buildroot for RPi3 B+ without X server (console only). Monitor connected on HDMI.
I want to keep the monitor on.

After 10 minutes (if I'm not wrong) of no keyboard activity the screen turns off.
From my old notes I did the following:

```
echo -ne "\033[9;0]" >> /etc/issue
```

but it does not work. I find a lot of advice but only for X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit/disable the timeout as explained in the Raspberry Pi Documentation section [Configuring Screen Blanking / On console](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-screen-blanking).

In `/boot/cmdline.txt` add `consoleblank=X` where `X` is the number of seconds of inactivity (for example `consoleblank=120` will wait for two minutes).

If you want to disable the feature, set `X` to zero: `consoleblank=0`.

Answer (score 0):

I probably do not bring an easy solution but I do provide some ideas.

Some quick questions first: Did you do reboot or do some action that makes `issue` to be copied to the terminal? Is not `issue` corrupted by excess control characters?  What is the result of plain `echo -ne "\033[9;0]` -- does it change the behaviour?

I confirm that the echo sequence works on very recent Ubuntu. (The plain echo; I did not try `issue`.)

Your echo command corresponds to the line

```
 ESC [ 9 ; n ]       Set screen blank timeout to n minutes.
```

in [`man 4 console_codes`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html).

But the support may possibly be conditional - compilation of the code may possibly be skipped in builds for smallest machines.

You may try to compile a small program that would use

```
       TIOCLINUX, subcode=TIOCL_SETVESABLANK
              Handles the Power Saving feature of the new generation of
              monitors.  VESA screen blanking mode is set to argp[1],
              which governs what screen blanking does:

              0      Screen blanking is disabled.
```

or

```
      TIOCLINUX, subcode=4
              Unblank the screen.
```

from  [`man 4 ioctl_console`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_console.2.html)